# Unable to define variables while using "Run Shell Script" in Automator

Tags: macos, shell, automator

At the moment I am running following script in Automator, and it runs perfectly fine:

```
#Copy Originals to SS1 on the main Server
find /Volumes/styleshoot/TJXE-HHPS-SS01/ -type f -exec cp -p {} "/Volumes/Hams Hall Workspace/StyleShoot1_WIP" \;

#Make Directory for Styleshoot 1 Backups
mkdir -p /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/SS\ Backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1

#Copy SS1 for into Backup folder
find /Volumes/styleshoot/TJXE-HHPS-SS01/ -type f -exec mv {} /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/SS\ Backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1 \;
```

Although, I was planning to make it cleaner while introducing some variable, for e.g.:

```
Original="/Volumes/styleshoot/TJXE-HHPS-SS01/"
Backup="/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/SS\ Backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1"
MainServer="/Volumes/Hams Hall Workspace/StyleShoot1_WIP"

mkdir -p "$Backup"

find "$Original" -type f -exec cp -p {} "$MainServer" \;
find "$Original" -type f -exec mv {} "$Backup" \;
```

But when I run it - nothing happens. I've found many similar problems like this on this forum, where the main solution would be to remove spaces around `=`  .Though it has no affect on the output. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check the directory `/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace`. This is not the same as the directory `/Volumes/Hams Hall Workspace`

Comment: @that other guy thanks! I wouldn't get any error's, it would simply pass everything without actually moving or copying. For some reason when I change `/Volumes/Hams Hall Workspace` to `/Volumes/Hams Hall Workspace` or another way around it didn't do anything too. Though your anwser made me test something else and now it works fine: I have simply removed `""` from `Backup="/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/SS\ Backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1"` it all works now just fine! `""`. Do you know maybe why would that be?

Comment: It should have moved all your files to `Hams\ Hall\ Workspace` instead of `Hams Hall Workspace`. When you double-escape things with both double quotes and backslashes, the backslashes will be considered literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will be googling this, the problem was when I tried to define `mkdir` location. `""` double quotation marks were not needed.

Change this:

```
Backup="/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/SS\ Backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1"
```

to This:

```
Backup=/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/SS\ Backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1
```

The final script is as below, and functions as desired:

```
Original="/Volumes/styleshoot/TJXE-HHPS-SS01/"
Backup=/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/SS\ Backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1
MainServer="/Volumes/Hams Hall Workspace/StyleShoot1_WIP"

mkdir -p "$Backup"

find "$Original" -type f -exec cp -p {} "$MainServer" \;
find "$Original" -type f -exec mv {} "$Backup" \;
```